# Highcharts Sankey Chart - Is it possible to create sticky node tooltips?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, sankey-diagram

I would to add a clickable link inside a Sankey chart's node tooltip.

I tried both the stickOnContact and hideDelay configurations.  They don't seem to work since every time my mouse leaves the node the tooltip it redraws itself as a point tooltip.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/d3nt57xa/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.from} to {point.to}, {point.weight}.'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        stickOnContact: true,
        distance:0,
        hideDelay:500
    },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Portugal', 'Brazil', 2],
            ['Brazil', 'France', 1],
            ['France', 'Brazil', 1],
           
        ],
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series',
        plotOptions: {
            sankey: {
                dataLabels: {
                    style: {
                      textOutline: 'none',
                      color: '#393e49',
                    },
                    enabled: true,
                },
                tooltip: {                   
                    stickOnContact: true
                },
                nodeWidth: 4,
                keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'custom'],
            }
        },
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to completely lock the tooltip in one place so that you can click on its content, in addition to setting `tooltip.stickOnContact: true`, you also need to disable the tooltip from following the mouse by changing the `tooltip.followPointer` property to `false` because, as it says documentation, for sankey this property is set to `true` by default.

You can add a link using the `tooltip.pointFormatter()` method, but you must remember to enable the use of HTML elements such as the `<a>` tag using the `tooltip.useHTML` property:

```js
tooltip: {
  stickOnContact: true,
  followPointer: false,
  useHTML: true,
  pointFormatter: function() {
    const point = this;
    return `
      ${point.from} → ${point.to}: <b>${point.weight}</b><br/>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.highcharts.com/">https://www.highcharts.com</a>
    `;
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/85fw40na/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.followPointer 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter